# Is there a plan to clean up Tags on ROS Answers site?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not suggesting that it be a manual effort.  There definitely should be an easy-button for admins to accomplish this task.  and maybe eventually it could even be completely automated.

But I just earlier asked a Universal Robots question and the following three Tags were all available for me to use:

```
universal-robot 
universal-robots 
universal_robot
```

Not knowing which was the most popular choice, I chose to tag my post with all 3.  Which is not ideal.  For several reasons.

Is there an effort or a plan to reduce examples like this to a single commonly used Tag?  It's website maintenance that would need to be done on a regular basis, because users will continue to make sloppy in-informed Tags.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271895/is-there-a-plan-to-clean-up-tags-on-ros-answers-site?/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-26**:
What's worse is that spam tags apparently live forever- I think the spammer here was caught and the posts deleted, but the tags are still polluting the system: https://answers.ros.org/tags/?t=tag&query=90013&search=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a specific plan to do so. Anyone with enough Karma is allowed to retag questions. In this case I'd strongly recommend using the tag that matches the package name, thus the underscored version. If anyone notices these inconsistencies please go ahead and homogenize the tags. Every little effort like this will help, even if you fix one or two at a time that helps.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
There's no admin interface available that allows mass CRUD of tags?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-02**:
There's also a feature request to avoid new users creating new tags: https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/issues/564

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-02**:
There's no admin interface for tags. I also opened a new Enhancement request to sort the suggestions by popularity as well as display the number of usages: https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/issues/734

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
I've +1-ed both. ASKBOT needs those improvements, badly.

An admin interface for tag CRUD would also be nice.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-10-02**:
I agree that every little effort will help.  But how do you incentivize and make it easy for site visitors to clean up tags?  Is there at least a Badge for it?  When tagging a new question, does the user interface make it simple and easy for that user to merge multiple tags into one?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know whether we are planning to do something like this, but it would definitely be a good idea (if only to get rid of all the tags that start with `#`: this is not twitter, and we don't use hashtags).

It would be nice if you could post an issue on [ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues), as your suggestion is really something that should be tracked there: your question will lose visibility after a while.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-10-02**:
Done.  Thanks.

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/161

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-26**:
There are also a bunch of tags that start with numbers that ought to go away, `1.ros` and even worse `0091` and other random numbers are tags for instance.  I wonder if it's a super error prone or time consuming job for someone with raw database access to try to remove or rename a bunch of bad tags, would the whole site have to go down for hours and may get broken?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-26**:
I was hoping if I eradicated every instance of `1.ros1` manually (it was only in ~10 questions) then that would disappear from the autocomplete suggestions, but it still pops up even if the user types in `ros1`, and will override what they typed after they press enter- what I've found is that if autocomplete is forcing a bad tag, switching to a different browser tab then back and the autocomplete box will be gone (at least in chrome), and then can press enter with the good tags.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-26**:
New issue https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/216